# In React Native how to pass store to Component when using NavigatorIOS?

Tags: react-native, store, navigator-ios

So originally my app was giving the store to the component fine in `index.ios.js` like so:

```
class Laybium extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AudioPlayerPage />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

However I wanted to add some more screens so I used `NavigatorIOS` like so:

```
class Laybium extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{ 
            component: Screen1,
            title: 'Screen 1: Pick username'
          }}
          style={{flex: 1}}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Which allowed my app to go to -> Screen 1 -> Screen 2 -> Screen 3 -> AudioPlayerPage(original Screen I displayed).

The transitions from Screen 1 -> 2 -> 3 work fine. But now I don't know how to provide the store and props to my Component `AudioPlayerPage`? Since wrapping the `NavigatorIOS` component within the `Provider` component doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my Screen3.js that transitions to my component `AudioPlayerPage`

```
class Screen3 extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this._onForward = this._onForward.bind(this);
    } 

    _onForward() {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        component: AudioPlayerPage,
        title: 'AudioPlayer: play synced song'
        // TODO: pass store
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Screen3</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._onForward}
                underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Go to AudioPlayerPage</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
      );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used NavigatorIOS myself, but using react-native-router-flux, I call `dispatch` from my components like this: `this.props.dispatch(someAction())`. As for the state of the store, I access it via the `mapStateToProps` callbacks. To receive the callback, a component should first be connected using the `connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName)`.

Comment: what version of react and react-native do you have in you package.json? I can't get mine to build with     "react": "15.0.2", "react-native": "0.26.3", "react-native-router-flux": "^3.35.0", with and without the ^

Comment: I'm using react 15.3.1, react-native 0.33.0, and react-native-router-flux ^3.35.0. I haven't tried it for iOS yet, only for Android.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Having a lot of trouble upgrading my react version to above 0.26 so can't even use the library right now :(

Comment: Ok, if you manage to do upgrade and still doesn't work, let me know